# Ubuntu and GitLab: Nginx and Apache, Two Network Interfaces

Tags: networking, apache2, nginx, gitlab

I'm attempting to configure my Ubuntu server to allow both Apache and Nginx (GitLab) to run side-by-side with each web server monitoring a different network interface.

I have the following interfaces bound to the specified network addresses:

`eno1: 192.168.0.100 [GitLab/nginx]`

`eno2: 192.168.0.110 [Apache]`

In the `gitlab.rb` configuration, I have specified the `external-url` as `http://192.168.0.100:80` and I have made no changes to the default Apache2 configuration files.

When I attempt to access the network addresses in my browser (Google Chrome), regardless of whether I enter `http://192.168.0.100` or `http://192.168.0.110`, I hit the GitLab landing page - Nginx appears to be taking over, regardless of what I specify for the `external_url`.

Further from this, in the `gitlab.rb` config file, I've also tried changing the following nginx configuration properties:

```
nginx['status'] = {
  "enable" => true,
  "listen_address" => ["192.168.0.100"],
  "port" => 80
}
```

Now when I venture to the `http://192.168.0.110` address, I get a 404 error but this comes from the Nginx web server - however, my understanding is that it shouldn't be listening to this address.

Can anyone offer any suggestions, please/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache is listening to all interfaces if you do not specify IP address.

Find `Listen 80` in `/etc/apache2/port.conf` and modify it to `Listen 192.168.0.110:80`.

It is the same with nginx.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I applied this change but also managed to find that I needed to edit the `gitlab.rb` file and add a `nginx['listen_addresses'] = ['192.168.0.100']` option to force ngix to only bind to one address